# Most Active Contributors Quarterly Report! - 4th Quarter 2017

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, quarterly

## Welcome Our SharePoint Stack Exchange Valued Contributors.

We would like to share the **Most Active Contributors Report** over the 4th Quarter 2017!

[image]

[image]

You can find the full list at [Stack Exchange Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/105/quarter/sharepoint/2017-10-01)

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering, We fully appreciate all the great contributions of SE members. Please keep your valuable contributing!

> **P.S.:** This report will be published Monthly (12 awards) / Quarterly  / Yearly based on the available data. Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback & precious suggestion!

Comment: why this practice is stopped after all? It was good..